# why the outputs are different in the while loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, logic

```
while($car_result1 = mysqli_fetch_object($car_connect1)){

<div class="portfolio all" data-cat="all">

<? echo $car_result1->car_gear; ?>  // output is stick

<img alt="Ay <?php if($car_result1->car_gear='auto'){ echo "Auto"; } else { echo "Stick"; };  ?> ">

<? echo $car_result1->car_gear; ?> // Output is Auto 

}
```

`car_gear` field is filled as "stick" in the database.
after the image tag, `car_gear` output changed as "Auto"

Why the result `$car_result1->car_gear;` change from "stick" to "Auto" ?

Comment: You have to close php or echo that html `echo $car_result1->car_gear;  ?> <div class="portfolio all" data-cat="all">`  Or it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
<img alt="Ay <?php if($car_result1->car_gear='auto')
```

With

```
<img alt="Ay <?php if($car_result1->car_gear=='auto')
```

Must be `==` to compare values. `=` will set the value to the variable.

Comment: wrong means the code doesnt work properly. Could you check the simplify section in the question part.  The output should be STICK..

Comment: Could you update the question with the actual code, after the modifications?